# Как загрузить список из базы данных SQLite во Flutter без кнопки Refresh?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

В качестве примера для работы с базой данных во Flutter использовал [вот эту статью](https://www.tutorialkart.com/flutter/flutter-sqlite-tutorial/).

В этом коде я убрал кнопку Refresh на вкладке Tab "View" и попробовал вызвать функцию без кнопки.

В результате код перестал правильно работать, теперь не знаю, что делать, чтобы загружать список сразу без необходимости нажимать сначала на кнопку:

```
Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: cars.length + 1,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (index == cars.length) {
                return RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Refresh'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _queryAll();
                    });
                  },
                );
              }
              return Container(
                height: 40,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '[${cars[index].id}] ${cars[index].name} - ${cars[index].miles} miles',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Пример из статьи я переделал, добавив в него возможность при первом запуске программы загружать демо-данные из готовой базы данных в assets, а также добавил возможность открывать и сохранять картинки.

Для тестирования программы создал файл базы данных и поместил его в assets.

Код полностью рабочий.

Но загружать список без кнопки Refresh не получается.

Мой код:

**pubsec.yaml**

```
name: flutter_sqlite_tutorial
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite:
  path:
  path_provider: any
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/cardb.db
```

**car.dart**

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter_sqlite_tutorial/dbhelper.dart';

class Car {
  int id;
  String name;
  int miles;
  Uint8List pict;

  Car(this.id, this.name, this.miles, this.pict);

  Car.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    name = map['name'];
    miles = map['miles'];
    pict = map['pict'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      DatabaseHelper.columnId: id,
      DatabaseHelper.columnName: name,
      DatabaseHelper.columnMiles: miles,
      DatabaseHelper.columnPict: pict,

    };
  }
}
```

**dbhelper.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'package:flutter_sqlite_tutorial/car.dart';



class DatabaseHelper {

  static final _databaseName = "cardb.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'cars_table';

  static final columnId = 'id';
  static final columnName = 'name';
  static final columnMiles = 'miles';
  static final columnPict = 'pict';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {

    // String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), _databaseName);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Construct the path to the app's writable database file:
    var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(dbDir, _databaseName);

// Delete any existing database:
//    await deleteDatabase(path);

    // Only copy if the database doesn't exist
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound){
      // Create the writable database file from the bundled demo database file:
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/cardb.db");
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: _databaseVersion,
        /*onCreate: _onCreate*/);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnMiles INTEGER NOT NULL,
            $columnPict BLOB NOT NULL,
          )
          ''');
  }

  // Helper methods

  // Inserts a row in the database where each key in the Map is a column name
  // and the value is the column value. The return value is the id of the
  // inserted row.
  Future<int> insert(Car car) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(table, {'name': car.name, 'miles': car.miles, 'pict': car.pict});
  }

  // All of the rows are returned as a list of maps, where each map is
  // a key-value list of columns.
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(table);
  }

  // Queries rows based on the argument received
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryRows(name) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(table, where: "$columnName LIKE '%$name%'");
  }

  // All of the methods (insert, query, update, delete) can also be done using
  // raw SQL commands. This method uses a raw query to give the row count.
  Future<int> queryRowCount() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table'));
  }

  // We are assuming here that the id column in the map is set. The other
  // column values will be used to update the row.
  Future<int> update(Car car) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = car.toMap()['id'];
    return await db.update(table, car.toMap(), where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Deletes the row specified by the id. The number of affected rows is
  // returned. This should be 1 as long as the row exists.
  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(table, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sqlite_tutorial/car.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sqlite_tutorial/dbhelper.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TutorialKart - Flutter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Holds image File
  File _image;
  File _imageUpdate;

//ImagePicker instance.
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  //ImageSource: Camera and Gallery.

  _getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);

    //if user doesn't take any image, just return.
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    setState(
      () {
        //Rebuild UI with the selected image.
        _image = File(imageFile.path);
      },
    );
  }
  _getImageUpdate(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);

    //if user doesn't take any image, just return.
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    setState(
          () {
        //Rebuild UI with the selected image.
        _imageUpdate = File(imageFile.path);
      },
    );
  }

  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  List<Car> cars = [];
  List<Car> carsByName = [];

  //controllers used in insert operation UI
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController milesController = TextEditingController();

  //controllers used in update operation UI
  TextEditingController idUpdateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameUpdateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController milesUpdateController = TextEditingController();

  //controllers used in delete operation UI
  TextEditingController idDeleteController = TextEditingController();

  //controllers used in query operation UI
  TextEditingController queryController = TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _showMessageInScaffold(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: "Insert",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "View",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Query",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Update",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Delete",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('TutorialKart - Flutter SQLite Tutorial'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car Name',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: milesController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car Miles',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: _image != null
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 300,
                                  height: 300,
                                  child: Image.file(
                                    _image,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                child: Text('No image selected'),
                              ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.gallery),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                            label: Text('gallery'),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.camera),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                            label: Text('camera'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Insert Car Details'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      String name = nameController.text;
                      int miles = int.parse(milesController.text);
                      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                      Uint8List pict = _image.readAsBytesSync();
                      _insert(name, miles, pict);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemCount: cars.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index == cars.length) {
                    return RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Refresh'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _queryAll();
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return Container(
                    height: 340,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '[${cars[index].id}] ${cars[index].name} - ${cars[index].miles} miles',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          Image.memory(
                            cars[index].pict,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: queryController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car Name',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        if (text.length >= 2) {
                          setState(() {
                            _query(text);
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            carsByName.clear();
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: carsByName.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              '[${carsByName[index].id}] ${carsByName[index].name} - ${carsByName[index].miles} miles',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: idUpdateController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car id',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: nameUpdateController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car Name',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: milesUpdateController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car Miles',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: _imageUpdate != null
                            ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            child: Image.file(
                              _imageUpdate,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                            : Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                          child: Text('No image selected'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => _getImageUpdate(ImageSource.gallery),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                            label: Text('gallery'),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => _getImageUpdate(ImageSource.camera),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                            label: Text('camera'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Update Car Details'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      int id = int.parse(idUpdateController.text);
                      String name = nameUpdateController.text;
                      int miles = int.parse(milesUpdateController.text);
                      ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                      Uint8List pict1 = _imageUpdate.readAsBytesSync();
                      _update(id, name, miles, pict1);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: idDeleteController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Car id',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Delete'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      int id = int.parse(idDeleteController.text);
                      _delete(id);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _insert(name, miles, pict) async {
    // row to insert
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      DatabaseHelper.columnName: name,
      DatabaseHelper.columnMiles: miles,
      DatabaseHelper.columnPict: pict
    };
    Car car = Car.fromMap(row);
    final id = await dbHelper.insert(car);
    _showMessageInScaffold('inserted row id: $id');
  }

  void _queryAll() async {
    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    cars.clear();
    allRows.forEach((row) => cars.add(Car.fromMap(row)));
    _showMessageInScaffold('Query done.');
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _query(name) async {
    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryRows(name);
    carsByName.clear();
    allRows.forEach((row) => carsByName.add(Car.fromMap(row)));
  }

  void _update(id, name, miles, pict) async {
    // row to update
    Car car = Car(id, name, miles, pict);
    final rowsAffected = await dbHelper.update(car);
    _showMessageInScaffold('updated $rowsAffected row(s)');
  }

  void _delete(id) async {
    // Assuming that the number of rows is the id for the last row.
    final rowsDeleted = await dbHelper.delete(id);
    _showMessageInScaffold('deleted $rowsDeleted row(s): row $id');
  }
}
```

Comment: В вашем километре кода никто разбираться не будет. Добавляйте конкретные примеры

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать функцию загрузки в initState:

```html
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Вызов функции загрузки
  }
```

Ну или ловить событие TabBar'а: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485466/how-to-detect-tabbar-change-in-flutter